# Using both \u.... and html entities in properties file?

Tags: java, properties, character-encoding, escaping

I'm stumbling upon a few xxx_fr.properties, xxx_en.properties, etc. files and I'm a bit surprised for they contain both html entities and `\uxxxx` escapings.

I guess the HTML entities are fine as long as these resources are served to something awaiting HTML but what about the `\uxxxx` escaping?

Does Java specify that `\uxxxx` escaping are fine in .properties file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - see the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) for `load(Reader)`, which states

> Characters in keys and elements can be
>   represented in escape sequences
>   similar to those used for character
>   and string literals.

and then clarifies that

> Only a single 'u' character is allowed in a Unicode escape sequence.

Hence a Unicode escape sequence containing a single 'u' character is definitely supported.

Note that there's nothing special going on here at loading time with HTML entities - the String `&amp;` for example would simply be seen within Java as a String containing 5 characters.  As you point out, this might be interpreted in a special way if it were output to some other component later.

On the other hand, the escape sequence `\u0061` would be seen within Java as the single-character string 'a', and would be indistinguishable from the file having contained that character instead.

Answer (score 3):

The \u type escaping is a standard Java way of representing Unicode characters. You can read about it in Java Internationalization FAQ. With "How do I specify non-ASCII strings in a properties file?" question being the one you're most interested in:

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp#properties-escape

And that's not Properties related only; you can use those in your typical Java code as well. See the Text Representation block:

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp#core-textrep

Comment: Minicki: +1 and thanks a lot.  I knew about the escaping in *.java* file.  It's in the properties that I was surprised.

Comment: Minicki: I've accepted 3 out of 5 questions and my questions are recent.  How is that low? ;)

Comment: @Gugussee: You had 20% at the time of my writing. But I said it as a little nudge for you; no hard feelings. Take it easy, G :)